# An unresolved question on stackoverflow was rebloged by random person

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

I posted a question to Stack Overflow regarding the Android Camera API's implementation within AOSP. The question was about a custom View called `PreviewFrameLayout` that they use for maintaining the image's aspect ratio across the preview so that it does not appear stretched.

The link to the question is here:  [Camera Preview does not appear full screen(displayed in a box)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21226682/camera-preview-does-not-appear-full-screendisplayed-in-a-box)

Today I found a blog called [amaKhulu Technologies](http://www.amakhulu.com/) who copied the Stack Overflow question as it is and reblogged it in it's entirety without any modifications.I would have been happy if that person changed the code or suggested a solution to the problem,added his twist to it or quoted it's source but they did not do so. (In the answer I accepted,the poster recommended an alternative approach). More over the blog also advertises software outsourcing as it's business.

I took a look at some of the other posts on the blog and they were all similar in  nature.

Here is a link to the blog post that copies my question: http://www.amakhulu.com/camera-preview-does-not-appear-full-screendisplayed-in-a-box/

What can/should I do to help Stack Overflow do something about it?

Comment: Hmm, alexa says it's an indian site. plagiarism.. well , not too much to do about it. wild intrenets

Comment: I would imagine once you post a question on Stack Overflow you lose control over where it winds up.  The appropriate question would be, "What can/should Stack Overflow do about it?"

Comment: @Pedantic what can I do to help StackOverlow do something about it(that is the implied question)?

Comment: @userwhatever don't imply, ask.  'twould benefit all by being explicit in your Q part of the Q&A.

Comment: How @pedantic... oh wait that's your name.

Comment: @hichris123 reported using contact form which I think should have an  Im reporting a SCRAPER reason.Thank you

Comment: The scrapper must be very pleased.  You just gave him free publicity, and a lot of traffic to his blog as a result.